# How can I access values in a scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray of WrappedArray's in java

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark

I am parsing a json file in SparkSQL in JAVA and I need to be able to access coordinates that are returned in what appears to be a WrappedArray of WrappedArrays. Here is the code:

```
df.registerTempTable("test_articles");
sql = "select gnip.profileLocations.geo.coordinates FROM test_articles";
DataFrame testData = sqlContext.sql(sql);
Row [] rowArray = testData.collect();

for(Row r:rowArray)
{
    if(r.get(0)!=null)
        System.out.println(r.get(0).toString());                
}
```

**OUTPUT: WrappedArray(WrappedArray(30.74806, 40.79944))**

**file.json**

```
"gnip": {
    "profileLocations": [{
        "objectType": "place",
        "geo": {
            "type": "point",
            "coordinates": [132.56111,
            35.07693]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Do you want a WrappedArray of WrappedArrays or do you want the WrappedArray flattened?

Comment: how to get flattened wrapped array without exploding? Eg. collect_set for {a,b} and {b,c} gives {{a,b}, {b,c}}, how to get {a,b,c}?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark SQL Row has `getList` method, that returns a Java list instead of WrappedArray. So, in the above example, one could say `r.getList(0)`